How do we create and manage general content pages
how / where can we create general content pages for our Contribution portal?  interested in the standalone version.

This is a difficult question to answer because there'll be multiple opinions, but here's one:
An analogy is buying a car that only does car functions, like driving from to A to B, with no additional capabilities, but then also wanting a radio. Standalone civi is just the car. The radio, entertainment system, cigarette lighter, cup holders, etc are provided by a different product. If you want it bundled you need the bundled system.
So you have a couple choices:

Use civi with a cms.
Use civi standalone, and separately install a cms. There's a couple choices here too as to how to set that up, and whether you need them to be under the same domain. At a minimum they can be completely separate with different domains and just have links in your content pages to civi pages.
Use civi standalone, and do the content-pages old-school, without a cms and just making html pages which you upload manually to the server.

